# Can't Texture Paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I came back to my 3d model after a while, and whenever I try to texture paint, nothing happens.  How do I fix this?

[image: Did I do something wrong?]

Answer (score 2):

Your texture mask is black, it means that everywhere will be no brush. Make your texture mask white or delete this.

And, most likely, you should put your cloud texture in place of texture mask, with mapping "random" or "view plane"